# How can I run android background service "forever"?

Tags: android, service, background

I looked through all the posts about it in here and in android documentation about service.
I still can't understand how to do it.

I want to write application that collects battery data all the time **event when the UI is closed**. I found that I need to use a service for this with BindService & StrartService so the UI Activity could communicate with the service and the service could also run by it self in case the UI activity closes.

The thing that I can't understand is how do I make the service run "forerver" even when I close it with android app manager. For example: Whatsapp application even if I close it with the app manager in the moment that someone sends me a message I still get it and whatsapp turns on.

Do I need to use thread (runnable interface with run function) or what?

Comment: Simple never shut down the service

Comment: In that case if the simple user will shut down my app using app manager it won't be shutdown?

Comment: isthis related 2 ur question??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434179/how-to-keep-a-service-running-in-background-even-after-user-quits-the-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254161/how-to-keep-service-running-after-force-stop

Comment: Have u got the answer from above links

Comment: From this two post I understand that there isn't a way to do what I need? (I don't want to use the "malware" way...) If this is the case can you explain how does whatsapp work?

Comment: Nope man.........I am nt telling that..But there is always a probability

Comment: U just kinda contradicted this two posts. I will wait maybe some one knows a way to do it or explain me about whatsup or any other similar app

Answer (score 2):

You may try to override `onStartCommand()` in your service and `return START_STICKY;` to let the system know your service should run until it terminates itself.

Comment: @AlexKapustian first of all you need to extends from IntentService not Service, onStartCommand is a method from IntenService and onBind From Service.