# Service does not restart after being killed , even after Return_STICKY

Tags: android, service, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep service running after force-stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254161/how-to-keep-service-running-after-force-stop)

Hi this is the piece of code i am using to create a service.
The service is tried to manually stop in settings -> manage apps -> running services
Even after Returning-Sticky .... Service Does not Restart.
Please Help. Any help will be appreciated

The Code is :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", 0).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", 0).show();
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "On Start Command - service started", 0).show();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");
    **return START_STICKY;**

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force-stop will stop *anything* of your app from running again until manually run by the user.

To better simulate your process being terminated due to low memory conditions, swipe your app out of the recent tasks list (ICS and higher), or use a third-party task manager.

Comment: so is there a way to avoid force stop functionality ?

Comment: @android.learner.fresher: Not from an ordinary SDK application. I think some firmware apps have the ability to disable the Force Close button.

Comment: If u say so , I would like to point out that Kaspersky Parental Control in android 2.2 is able to prevent force stop of app completely by disabling the application 

Secondly , Trend micro application restarts all its services even after force stop .

Comment: @android.learner.fresher: If they do so on Android 3.1+, they are exploiting some security flaws to accomplish their aims.